# Как заставить пустой div без height отображать фоновую картинку?

Tags: html, css, background

Есть пустой блок с фоновой картинкой:

```
div {
  background-image: url('pic.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Можно ли заставить этот блок (без height и без содержимого) отображать фоновую картинку и принимать высоту этой картинки?

По умолчанию, если пустому блоку не задать высоту, его просто не видно (несмотря на наличие фоновой картинки). А если задать блоку какую-то высоту, то при изменении размера экрана картинка пропорционально ужимается, а высота блока не меняется, и внизу образуется пустота.

Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

**P.S.** Вставлять картинку в блок как img не предлагать.

Comment: padding-bottom: XX%; /*-- value padding-botttom = height/width*100=xx%  --*/

Comment: @soledar10 супер!! спасибо большое! надо ж было в виде ответа писать, а не комментария )

Comment: С свг так не вышло.С свг так не вышло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант добавить `padding-bottom`

```
padding-botttom = height/width*100=XX%
```

Пример

Высота изображения 150px

Ширина изображения 200px

Значение `padding-botttom = 150/200*100=75%`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/fall-1072821__340.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Это не работает, как ни крути. при адаптивной высоте у вас просто не будет отображаться фон. проверено!

Comment: @Дарк приведите пример.

Comment: @soledar10 , хорошее решение, но есть нюанс: вертикальный `padding` в процентах считается от `ширины родителя`. И если по каким-то причинам ширина блока с фоном станет меньше (или больше) 100% ширины родителя - все пропорции накроются известно чем. Лучше давать такому блоку псевдоэлемент с `display: block; width: 100%; padding-top: X%`

Answer (score 0):

`padding-bottom:120px` или `padding-bottom:40%` - Ваш выход. Пример:

```
div {
  background-image: url('pic.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom:10px
}
```